# How to type check spread operator in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Is there a way to make this not compile? (because it does...)

```
const bar: { a: string } = {
    a: '',
    ...{b: ''}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was shocked to find that this passed the type checker!

After poking around a bit, I have a strong hunch about why this is occurring, but I haven't found any official word to back it up yet.
As such, this isn't an answer, but a conversation-starter that's too long for a comment.
That's all to say, take what follows with a grain of salt.

I suspect that TypeScript's "ascription"/"annotation" mechanism allows for some wiggle-room based on subtypes.
Specifically, when we write:

```
const foo: Foo = bar;
```

as long as `bar`'s type is a *subtype* of `Foo`, this seems to pass the checker with flying colors.
Here's a specific example:

```
class Foo {
  public a: string;
}

// `Bar` is a subtype of `Foo`
class Bar extends Foo {
  public b: string;
}

const foo: Foo = new Bar();
//         ^^^       ^^^ This is just fine!
```

Furthermore, since TypeScript's notion of subtyping is "structural", the following is also perfectly acceptable:

```
class Foo {
  a: string;
}

// `Quux` is structurally the same as (and therefore a subtype of) `Foo`
class Quux {
  a: string;
}

const foo: Foo = new Quux();
```

With this [theory] in mind, your example is accepted by the checker because `{ a: string; b: string }` is a subtype of `{ a: string }`.

In conclusion, *if* this is correct, I don't think there is a way to coax the type checker into rejecting your example.

*Edit*: This isn't the complete story.
As @apflieger points out, this theory doesn't explain why

```
const foo: { a: string } = {
  a: 'test',
  b: 'test',
};
```

is rejected.
It appears as though the spreading is critical here.

It could be that the type of

```
{
  a: 'test',
  ...{ b: 'test' }
}
```

is inferred as something like `{ a: string } & { b: string }`, whereas in the previous case it is inferred as `{ a: string; b: string }`.

Comment: For classes yes, but for raw interfaces it's surprising. In my example without the spread operator, it doesn't compile: const foo: {a: string} = {a: '', b: ''} // Fails

Comment: That is a very good point. It definitely appears to depend on whether you spread `{ b: '' }` or not.